# How to add a attribute to remove link after use ajax to preload images into dropzone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, dropzone.js

I want to add an attribute to remove link like after upload:

`$(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('id', response.fileID);`

into:

```
 init: function() {
    var thisDropzone = this;
    $.get("url", function( data ) {
        // alert("Done");
        // console.log("Data: ", data);
        $.each(data, function(key,value){ //loop through it
            console.log(value);
        var mockFile = { name: value.image_file_name, size: value.image_file_size }; // here we get the file name and size as response 

        thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropzone, mockFile);

        thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile, value.url); //uploadsfolder is the folder where you have all those uploaded files
        // file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success"); 
        thisDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile); // remove process bar
        // thisDropzone.find('.dz-remove').attr('id', value.id); => here


    });
      }, "json" );
  }
```

How can I do that? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here you can upload multiple files using the dropzone js if you want to delete file after uploading you have to follow the below code.
In this code following points covered

1. You can upload multiple images 
2. remove file from server

```
$("#imageStorage").dropzone({
            init: function() {
                var thisDropzone = this;
                var json_data = <?php echo json_encode(explode(',',$this->layout()->EditableData['listing_space_images']));?>;
                var old_data_json = <?php echo json_encode(explode(',',$this->layout()->EditableData['listing_space_orignalname']));?>;
                $.each(json_data, function(key,value){ 
                    if(value != ''){
                        var mockFile = { name: old_data_json[key], size: value, status: Dropzone.ADDED};
                        thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropzone, mockFile);
                        thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile, storage_img_path+'/thumb/'+value);
                    }
                });
            },
            maxFiles: 2000,
            url: baseUrl + "/storage_image",
            success: function (file, response) {
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                var image_name = result['media_path'];
                var orignal = file.name ;
                var oldname = $('#orignalname').val();
                var value=  $('#input_image_container').val();
                $('.dz-remove').attr('id',image_name);
                if(value == ''){
                           //set orignal name and new name to the hidden input field when input field is null
                    $('#input_image_container').val(image_name);
                    $('#orignalname').val(orignal);
                }
                else{
                 //set orignal name and new name to the hidden input field when input field is not null
                    value = value + ',' +image_name;
                    oldname = oldname +','+orignal;
                    $('#input_image_container').val(value);
                    $('#orignalname').val(oldname);
                }   
            },
            error:function(file){
                var _this = this;
                _this.removeFile(file); 
                //error when select invalid file 
            },
            acceptedFiles: "image/*",
            accept: function(file, done) {
                if (file.type != "image/jpeg") {
                    done("Error! Files of this type are not accepted");
                }
                else { done(); }
            },
            autoDiscover: false,
            addRemoveLinks:true,
            previewsContainer: "#previewContainer",
            removedfile:function(file){
                var _this = file;
                var orignal= $('#orignalname').val();
                var changed = $('#input_image_container').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: baseUrl + "/delete_image/"+_this.name,
                    type: "POST",
                    data:{orignalname :orignal,server_name:changed},
                    dataType:'Text',
                    success:function(result){
                        if(result){
                           //Sucess Code when image delete from server using ajax
                            }else{
                                //Error code
                            }
                        }else{
                            //Error code
                        }
                    }
                }); 

            }
        });
```